# android how to add permission to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

i want to add permission to read `email` from the facebook android sdk.

#### code

```
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    et_firstName.setText(user
                                            .getFirstName());
                                    et_lastName.setText(user
                                            .getLastName());
                                    Log.e("data",
                                            user.asMap().get("email")
                                                    + "");
                                    URL image_value;
                                    try {
                                        image_value = new URL(
                                                "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                                        + user.getId()
                                                        + "/picture");
                                        iv_profileImage
                                                .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                                                        .decodeStream(image_value
                                                                .openConnection()
                                                                .getInputStream()));
                                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
```

#### what i have tried

I read a lot that this can be done using `loginbutton` but i don't want to use loginbutton.

also i read that if i don't want to use `logingbutton`, i have to use `openfor` session, but i didn't know how to use that

#### please help me, i have been trying for it for like a week

Answer (score 1):

If you use a LoginButton, use:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```

If you start the Session yourself, use:

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
```

requests/permissions helpfull link: `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`

After successfull login, try the request again including the email field.